# How to don't allow access unpublished apps from PlayStore and AppStore?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play-services, app-store-connect

I have unpublished my app from both stores, users that have already download the app thay still can access even though is unpublished, is there a way I can block their access and avoid they keep accessing to the app from the stores?

I did unpublished my apps and thought this would do the job but they still have access

Comment: You want to force uninstall something from a device you don't own?  That's pretty toxic.  My phone, I get to say when an app is removed not you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: No, you cannot remove the app from someone who already has it installed.

Comment: You cad do it but for that you have to code it in your app that will check every timer whether app is available on store or not. if not show exit app dialog